# Ignite near caches causing high heap usage

Tags: ignite

If I create a cache with near cache, I can see the near entries rising as
expected - up to about the limit defined by the eviction policy. What is unexpected - is that the onheap count goes much higher than this - apparently reflecting the total number of remote entries.

For clarity, I do not have a separate on-heap cache configured - only a near cache with max 1000 entries.

It seems that the near cache causes a build-up of on-heap entries that do not get evicted. Is this a cause for concern?

When testing with limited available heap, I can see that adding even a small near cache (e.g. max 1 entry) can cause a JVM OOM condition against a cache with a large number of entries.

Test run was:

```
IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = createCache();
for (int i=0; i<NUM_ENTRIES; i++) {
    cache.put(i, "Entry " + i);
    cache.get(i);

    LOGGER.info("Iteration " + i
            + " entries " + cache.size(CachePeekMode.PRIMARY)
            + " heap " + cache.size(CachePeekMode.ONHEAP)
            + " near " + cache.size(CachePeekMode.NEAR));
}
```

The cache was created as follows:

```
private IgniteCache<Integer, String> createCache() {

    LruEvictionPolicyFactory<Integer, String> nearEvictPlcFactory
            = new LruEvictionPolicyFactory<>(1000);

    NearCacheConfiguration<Integer, String> nearCfg = new NearCacheConfiguration<Integer, String>()
            .setNearEvictionPolicyFactory(nearEvictPlcFactory);

    CacheConfiguration<Integer, String> config = new CacheConfiguration<Integer, String>()
            .setName(CACHE_NAME)
            .setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
            .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC)
            .setStatisticsEnabled(true)
            .setBackups(0)
            .setNearConfiguration(nearCfg);

    Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();
    return ignite.getOrCreateCache(config);
}
```

Gives output like below - with a near cache of max 1000 entries the heap size goes over 50k when two nodes are running (0 backups):

```
INFO 09-25 16:56:28.380 [main] : Iteration 0 entries 1 backup 0 heap 0 near 0
...
INFO 09-25 16:56:38.477 [main] : Iteration 98000 entries 98001 backup 0 heap 50981 near 1000
...
INFO 09-25 16:56:38.541 [main] : Iteration 99000 entries 99001 backup 0 heap 51471 near 1000
```

Comment: Can you share how you create your cache?

Comment: Now added to the description above

Comment: This does not appear to be a problem. I see the same behaviour. I wonder if it's a remnant of when Ignite has an on-heap cache, or is measuring something else. (Not adding as an answer because I'm not completely sure what's going on, but thought it was worth saying that it appears to be normal.)